# How do I resolve the HostUnreachableError error?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

`Using logstash, I put data into multiple tables.`

The data went in well, and the error occurred.

**my .conf file code**

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://awslink/db_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from access_token"
        type => "access_token"
        tracking_column => "table_1"
        use_column_value => true
        }


    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://awslink:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from activity"
        type => "activity"
        tracking_column => "table_2"
        use_column_value => true
        }
}

output {
    if[type] == "access_token"  {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "test_db1"
            }
    }
    if[type] == "activity"  {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "test_db2"
            }
    }
 }
```

**The way I tried to solve the error.**

1. sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf
2. elasticsearh - nofile 65536 , elasticsearch - memlock unlimited (add)

`logstash execute message 1`

```
  66378       org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:318)
  66378       java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:834)
  66378   tz:
  66376       {:max_work_threads=>1}
  66378     ENV['TZ']:
  66378     Time.now: 2021-05-20 02:17:00 +0000
  66376       frequency: 0.3  66378   scheduler:

  66378     object_id: 2358
  66378     opts:

  66362     work_queue: 0  66378       {:max_work_threads=>1}
  66378       frequency: 0.3


  66344     work_queue: 0} 66362 .
  66378       scheduler_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0xf93e49e>

  66378       trigger_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0x7e93e747>
} 66344 .  66378     uptime: 402.771594 (6m42s771)

  66378     down?: false
  66378     threads: 2
  66378       thread: #<Thread:0x3f3320c6>
  66378       thread_key: rufus_scheduler_2358
  66378       work_threads: 1
  66378         active: 1
  66378         vacant: 0
  66378         max_work_threads: 1
  66378       mutexes: {}
  66378     jobs: 1
  66378       at_jobs: 0
  66378       in_jobs: 0
  66378       every_jobs: 0
  66378       interval_jobs: 0
  66378       cron_jobs: 1
  66378     running_jobs: 1
  66378     work_queue: 0
} 66378 .

  66320       every_jobs: 0
  66320       interval_jobs: 0
  66320       cron_jobs: 1
  66320     running_jobs: 1
  66320     work_queue: 0
} 66320 .
  66376       scheduler_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0x3b832939>
  66376       trigger_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0x9e73529>
  66376     uptime: 402.760709 (6m42s760)
  66376     down?: false
  66376     threads: 2
  66376       thread: #<Thread:0x40f16fe8>
  66376       thread_key: rufus_scheduler_2574
  66376       work_threads: 1
  66376         active: 1
  66376         vacant: 0
  66376         max_work_threads: 1
  66376       mutexes: {}
  66376     jobs: 1
  66376       at_jobs: 0
  66376       in_jobs: 0
  66376       every_jobs: 0
  66376       interval_jobs: 0
  66376       cron_jobs: 1
  66376     running_jobs: 1
  66376     work_queue: 0
} 66376
```

**-> `Q1. What does the phrase above indicate?`**

**`logstash error message: HostUnreachableError`**

```
[2021-05-20T02:17:08,036][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][597c5b3125387cfea834a5fc87ade05896b0b0a1c586053e4804e94fe784125e] Marking url as dead. Last error: [LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError] Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://52.188.20.167:9200/][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out {:url=>http://52.188.20.167:9200/, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://52.188.20.167:9200/][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}

[2021-05-20T02:35:08,355][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][c5dc00ad52b34b848fcb59d7c9a36f43d5ceaab043c475b688f08606fa144ad0] Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch' but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down! {:error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://52.188.20.167:9200/][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError", :will_retry_in_seconds=>2}
```

**-> Q2. What should I do to solve this error?**

Through elasticsearch, the data went in well.

`However, after some time, the corresponding error message occurred.`

- Through localhost:9200, elasticsearch has been confirmed to be working.
- Through localhost:9200, kibana was confirmed to be working.